# Putting a zero in a Report Builder expression

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I have an expression in my report in Report Builder that can have 0 for the sum but when it is displayed it shows "There are Job Reqs at this time."  instead of "There are 0 (or 'no') Job Reqs at this time.".  How can I get the 0 (or 'no') in this statement?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are asking, but it sounds like if it is zero, it is actually returning blank. So doing something like this:

```
=IIF(
    ISNOTHING(Fields!MightBeZeroValue.Value) OR 
    Fields!MightBeZeroValue.Value) = "", 
    "0", 
    Fields!MightBeZeroValue.Value)
```

This means that if the 'MightBeZeroValue' field is null or empty, display zero, otherwise display that field. Hope this helps.

If you can do this within the SQL, then even better:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(MightBeZeroValue.Value, 0) AS MightBeZeroValue
FROM
    SomeTable
```